# I want to open 2nd tab from 1st tab when I click on item in listview

Tags: android-tabactivity

I have 3 tabs. 
1st tab contains 1st activity.
2nd tab contain 2nd activity.

1st activity contains list of items.

When I click on item in list, I'm passing it's information via intent to 2nd activity in 2nd tab.

Now I wanted to start 2nd tab displaying 2nd activity containing the information from 1st activity.

how to achieve this?